# Differentiation of the norm of a scalar function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $r(t)$ be is a vector function and $n(t) = |r(t)|$ the scalar function defined by the norm of r(t), then:

$$n(t)n'(t) = r(t) \cdot r'(t)$$

Where does the dot product come from?  If I differentiate $n(t)$ I get the usual multiplication:

$\begin{aligned} n(t) & |r(t)| \implies n(t) = \sqrt{(r(t))^2} \implies n'(t) = \frac{r(t)r'(t)}{|r(t)|} \implies n(t)n'(t) = r(t)r'(t).  \end{aligned}$

Comment: Is $r$ a vector-valued function? If yes, then $n(t)=\sqrt{r_1^2(t) + r_2^2(t) + \dots + r_n^2(t) }= \sqrt{r(t) \cdot r(t)}$. Also, in this case: what's the meaning of $r(t)r'(t)$ in terms of coordinates of $r$ and $r'$?

Comment: Because r is a vector so squaring it is equivalent to taking the dot product with itself $r^2=r\cdot r$. Otherwise what would squaring a vector mean

Comment: Oh, I see. Many thanks guys.